# Amazon S3 Delete Object Policy Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

we are using Amazon S3 services and bucket for storing our data, now I have a problem, everything is working, but I want to restrict Delete object permissions only on few tables inside bucket, somehow this is not working:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1448899531000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:List*"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                 "*"
             ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1461061827000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-11e3g59cf34bh-eu-west-1/report_file_html/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-11e3g59cf34bh-eu-west-1/market_intelligence_result_sets/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I checked the ARN for bucket and it is "arn:aws:s3:::cf-templates-11e3g59cf34bh-eu-west-1" as excpected, market_intelligence and report_file_html tables also exist in the bucket, so I want to limit delete object action only to these tables,but from my PHP app, I get 403 error, permission denied to delete an object.

Using Amazon IAM Policy Validator, these rules validates successfully, but then using aws CLI, I get access denied error when calling DeleteObject.

Comment: What is the command being issued from the PHP app? Where did you put the above policy (on an IAM User/Role, or elsewhere)? Did you try doing the Delete via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) using the same set of credentials?

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein , I did tried deleting it from AWS CLI, no problem whatsoever doing that.. Policy is attached to production role and my bucket is also under production. I used IAM Policy simulator to validate this, it says all good. I used 'DeleteObject' command from php

Comment: Sorry, I mistaked you, using AWS CLI, actually returns me access denied for 'DeleteObject' operation

Comment: Do you have versioning enabled in your s3 bucket ?

Comment: If the AWS CLI also returns `Access Denied`, then you should debug the permissions issue. Make extra sure that the above policy is attached to the credentials you are using for the Delete. Something is incorrectly configured. Start by modifying the policy to allow delete on _anything_, then narrow it down until you figure out the discrepancy.